# Name for types of fonts (sans-serif with bevelled stems)

Tags: typography, font-recommendation, typefaces, style-identification, terminology

I want to find fonts like the one used [here](http://flatiron.com), which is SuperGroteskWebPro.  It is notable that in this font the *f, T* and *t* have cuts on edges at some angles. It is also a very clean font and gives a clean feel like Roboto:

[image]

I am looking for fonts like this one. How do I search for it? What is this style called? What fonts are similar to this?

Answer (score -2):

I think "Noveo Sans" related to the above image font. Please check the link it'll helps you.
https://www.fontspring.com/similar/fontsite/noveo-sans

Comment: thanks! I found out that these type of probably called sans grotesque

Comment: @penduDev: Sans-serifs and grotesques are two mostly overlapping classes of typefaces, but none of these terms implies bevelled stems such as you have been asking for. (Also note that you are allowed and encouraged to self-answer your question, if you think that you found a solution yourself.)